# Is 哲学【てつがく】 the correct word to use when talking about Philosophy in regards to the Major?

Tags: translation, word-choice

I want to be able to say "my major is philosophy" and so I looked up the word for philosophy, but I'm not sure if it would be correct use the same word when talking about it as a major in college?

In other words, would this be correct?

私は専攻が哲学です。
【わたしはせんこうがてつがくです。】

Thank you!!

ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 7):

Yes, 哲学 is the correct word for philosophy (the subject) in Japanese.

The word 哲学 was basically invented in the 19th century for this very purpose and popularized by Nishi Amane ([journal source here](http://philosophy-japan.org/wpdata/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Tetsugaku_Vol1_12.Kanayama.pdf), [wiki](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%93%B2%E5%AD%A6)).

In Japanese, philosophy is sometimes applied by extension to non-Western thinkers, but if someone wants to avoid calling non-Western things philosophy, then [思想]{しそう} is often used instead.

Put another way, 哲学 is exactly the right word for Western philosophy, because it is a word that was created precisely to translate the term philosophy.

As naruto explained to me, your sentence is a natural way of stating your major:

> 私は専攻が哲学です
>
> 私は哲学が専攻です

In addition, you could use:

> 私の[専攻]{せんこう}は[哲学]{てつがく}.

or in many contexts,

> [哲学]{てつがく}[専攻]{せんこう}です.

Comment: 「私は専攻が哲学です」も「私は哲学が専攻です」も合っており自然な日本語です。(もちろん「専攻は何ですか」と聞かれた場合の答えなら後者ですが)

Comment: @naruto 勉強になりました。その形を頭に入れておきます。